# Master Data Services deleting rows from UI

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, master-data-services, master-data-management, mds

We have duplicate data in entities in Master data services and not in staging tables. how can we delete these? We cannot delete each row because these are more than 100?

Answer (score 0):

Did you create a view for this entity? see: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff487013.aspx
Do you access to the database via SQL Server Management Studio?
If so:

1. Write a query against the view that returns the value of the Code field for each record you want to delete.
2. Write a query that inserts the following into the staging table for that entity: code (from step 1), BatchTag, ImportType of 4 (delete)
3. Run the import stored proc EXEC [stg].[udp_YourEntityName_Leaf] See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231028.aspx
4. Run the validation stored proc  see: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231023.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Use ImportType 6 instead of 4 as the deletion will fail if the Code which you are trying to delete is being referenced by a domain based attribute in other entities if you use ImportType 4. Rest all the steps will remain same as told by Daniel.

Answer (score 0):

I deleted the duplicate data from the transaction tables which cleared the duplicates from the UI also.

Answer (score 0):

MDS comes out-of-the-box with two front-end UIs:

- Web UI
- Excel plugin

You can use both of them to easily delete multiple records. I'd suggest using the excel plugin.

Are there any Domain-based attributes linked to the entity you're deleting values from? If so, if the values are related to child entity members, you'll have to delete those values first.